# Identifying an ideal class, identify its norm form, and vice versa

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n > 1$ be a positive integer. By a *norm form* of degree $n$ we mean a homogeneous polynomial $F$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and splits completely into linear factors over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Define the *discriminant* of $F$ as follows. First write

$$\displaystyle F(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = a_F \prod_{i=1}^n L_i(x_1, \cdots, x_n),$$

where $L_1(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = x_1 + \alpha_2^{(1)} x_2 + \cdots + \alpha_n^{(1)} x_n$ with $\alpha_i \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for $i = 2, \cdots, n$ and $a_F \in \mathbb{Z}$, and such that the $L_i$'s are conjugates of $L_1$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$. Next consider the matrix

$$\displaystyle M_F = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \alpha_2^{(1)} & \cdots &\alpha_n^{(1)} \\ 1 & \alpha_2^{(2)} & \cdots &\alpha_n^{(2)} \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & \alpha_2^{(n)} & \cdots & \alpha_n^{(n)}  \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now define the discriminant of $F$, $\Delta(F)$ by

$$\displaystyle \Delta(F) = (a_F \det(M_F))^n.$$

When $n = 2$, this agrees with the usual discriminant of binary quadratic forms.

In the quadratic case, a given norm form (binary quadratic form) carries with it the following two pieces of information:

1) The discriminant $\Delta(F)$ parametrizes uniquely a quadratic order $\mathcal{O}_F$; and

2) The $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence class of $F$ parametrizes an ideal class in the order $\mathcal{O}_F$.

My question is, how does one do this when $n \geq 3$? That is, given a norm form $F$, how does one recover the order $\mathcal{O}_F$ such that the $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence class of $F$ represents an ideal class over $\mathcal{O}_F$? When $n \geq 3$, the discriminant no longer parametrizes the orders themselves, so it is unclear as to what order each norm form corresponds to (or if this is unique).

Further, given an order $\mathcal{O}$ and an ideal class $\mathcal{C}$ in the ideal class group, how does one identify the (equivalence class of) norm form for the ideal class?